# Using bootstrap and less with Angular 2 webpack

Tags: angular, sass, webpack, less

I am new to Angular 2. I am unable to use less file in my application.
structure

```
-src
  |-app
     |-app.component.ts, app.component.scss
  |-assets
     |-css
        |-variable.less, theme.css, custom.css
```

my webpack config is

```
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
    'app': './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.json', 'css', 'less', 'html'],
    modules: [helpers.root('src'), 'node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      //Load sourcemaps
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'source-map-loader',
        exclude: [
          // these packages have problems with their sourcemaps
          helpers.root('node_modules/rxjs'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@ngrx'),
          helpers.root('node_modules/@angular2-material'),
        ]
      },
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader',
                'angular2-template-loader',
                'angular2-router-loader'],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    }, {
      test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/,
      loader: 'url?limit=10000'
    }, {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: 'json-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader',
      exclude: [helpers.root('./index.html')]
    }, {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
    }, {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
    }, {
        test: /\.less$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'raw-loader!less-loader'
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
      loader: 'file'
    }, {
        test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
        loader: 'inline-svg-loader'
      }
   ],
  },
```

my app.component.scss is as follows:

```
@import "../assets/css/theme.css";
@import "../assets/css/custom.css";
@import "../assets/css/variables.less";
```

I am using it like this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.scss'],
})
```

I am getting an error

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
Module build failed:
undefined
         ^
      Invalid CSS after "@gray-base:": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "#000;"
```

theme.css and variable.less are from bootstrap. I have included bootstrap npm module in my vendor. variable.less also has entry for svg icons.

Can someone please help me understand this error? I thought my less file was being handled by less-loader.

Is there a better way to include css in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are importing a LESS file into an SCSS file, here:

```
@import "../assets/css/theme.css";
@import "../assets/css/custom.css";
@import "../assets/css/variables.less";
```

If you want to import `variables.less`, then you will need to compile it into CSS first (if it is a Bootstrap file, then I'm sure the .css is already stored somewhere).